# How can i display multiple images storing in meta box image field

Tags: wordpress, image, meta-boxes

I want to display multiple image coming from meta box image.It display 'Array' as a result. I want to show images insted of  'Array.'

Meta box image code in function.php file:

```
add_filter( 'rwmb_meta_boxes', 'YOURPREFIX_register_meta_boxes' );
 function YOURPREFIX_register_meta_boxes( $meta_boxes ) {
     $prefix = 'rw_';

      $meta_boxes[] = array(
         'id'         => 'personal3',
         'title'      => __( 'Image', 'textdomain' ),
         'post_types' => array( 'post', 'page' ),
         'fields'     => array(
             array(
                 'name' => __( 'Photo', 'textdomain' ),
                 'id'   => $prefix . 'Photo',
                 'type' => 'image',
                 'force_delete'     => false,
                 // Maximum image uploads
                 'max_file_uploads' => 4,
                // Display the "Uploaded 1/2 files" status
                 'max_status'       => true,
             ),
         )
     );
     return $meta_boxes; }
```

Display code in loop.php file:

```
<?php 
      echo $myvar = rwmb_meta( 'rw_Photo');
?>
```

Comment: please print_r( rwmb_meta( 'rw_Photo') ); and check array result. and add out in question.

Comment: It displays whole code, how can i show only 4 images?

Comment: please check my answer. let me know of any issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

array of images

add below foreach loop in your loop

```
 <?php
    $myvar_array = rwmb_meta( 'rw_Photo');
    foreach ( $myvar_array as $myvar_value )
    {
         //$myvar_value['url'] 
        ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $myvar_value['url']; ?>" />
        <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: It display none, please tell me exactly where to insert this code and how can i display 4 images? Right now i am using your code in loop.php file.

Comment: please give me website url. and please print_r(rwmb_meta( 'rw_Photo')); of this meta array in loop. so i can see out of data array. and i can create loop of above meta array.

Comment: I am using wordpress in local machine.

Comment: ok. add above code in loop.php file. and find full url of photos in array. and change the key of 'url' in $myvar_value['url']

Comment: OK, It's working. i just put your code in loop.php file and it display all 4 images. Thanx for helping me...:)